# Pandas: Select rows that match a string and Create a new column with that word

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas: Select rows that match a string and Create a new column with that word
I want to create a new column  Select rows that match a string and Create a new column(found) with that word

```
list_provided=["mul","the","have", "then"]
```

**how my dataframe looks**

```
id  text
a    simultaneous there the
b    simultaneous there
c    mul why
```

**Expected output**

```
id  text                        found
1    simultaneous there the      the
2    simultaneous there         
3    mul why                     mul
4    have the                    have, the 
5    then the late               then,the
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that something like this should work:

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.split() if i in list_provided])
```

Comment: yeah, just join them like: `df['text'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x.split() if i in list_provided]))`

Comment: @TRINADHNAGUBADI then use set: `df.text.apply(lambda x: ','.join(list(set([i for i in x.split() if i in list_provided]))))` is order important??

Comment: When text column contains multiple words by list_provided(list) `a    simultaneous there the the`
`simultaneous there` 
it is giving the ouput `the the` `then then` I need unique values

Comment: @TRINADHNAGUBADI yes, set gives unique values: `df.text.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set([i for i in x.split() if i in list_provided])))`

Comment: in the text contains `" line produces an error"`
`list_provided=["mul","the","have", "then","an error"]`
an error is not founding.please help out this error

Comment: "an error" are two words. in this case you'd need either to find strings (not words), or transform the data beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using a regex pattern:

```
pat = r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(list_provided) + r'\b'

df['found'] = df.text.str.findall(pat)


  id                    text        found
0  a  simultaneous there the        [the]
1  b      simultaneous there           []
2  c                 mul why        [mul]
3  d                have the  [have, the]
4  e           then the late  [then, the]
```

Comment: great solution. Faster because no apply here